# Function to convert GridView and Repeater in a JSON string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, gridview, repeater

I need a JavaScript function which will take the `ASP.NET` Repeater as input. The function must then parse through the object and return the data in the rows of the object as `JSON`.

Then, I can send the `JSON` back to the server to be `interpreted/parsed` and saved to the DB.

Comment: Your question isnt making much sense to me. You want to convert a server control to json, or the data that the controls are bound to?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is probably traversing the elements rendered by the `Repeater` and gathering the values into a javascript object. when you have that you can use json2's `stringify()` or jquery's `serialize()` or something similar to produce a json representation.